# Jenkins pipeline build a dockerfile which contains a base image of my dockerhub repository

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am extremely new to Jenkins. I tried out few basic pipeline examples which worked.

My concrete use case is following:

I have a base image in my docker hub repository : my_dockerhub_rep/myImage:v1

Now I want to build another image based on this base image through a Jenkins pipeline. 
So i wrote the following dockerfile :

```
FROM my_docker_hub_rep/myImage:v1

RUN /bin/bash -c 'echo entering in MC container'
```

To build this image from Jenkins, i wrote the following Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {

    agent { dockerfile {

    filename "/home/user/Desktop/Dockerfile"
    registryUrl ""
    registryCredentialsId 'dockerHub'


    }}
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'hello !'
                sh 'echo LM_LICENSE_FILE = $LM_LICENSE_FILE'
            }
        }
```

The jenkins server can successfully login to the docker repository at first but then as soon as it tries to fetch the base image it throws an error that pull access denied : repository doesnt exist or requires docker login.

What i dont understand is if it could login into the docker repo once then why not again ?

Here is the console output of jenkins :

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/docker_test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
$ docker login -u mydockerID-p ******** https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/docker_test@tmp/a548cbfa-5d55-4a2c-87a7-4954052d7e5b/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup)
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t b2f2e9020bdfdbcd1bc3d0a6f0f28b1c7abff41b -f /home/user/Desktop/Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.095kB

Step 1/8 : FROM my_docker_rep/myImage:v1
pull access denied for my_docker_rep/myImage, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

ps: i already added jenkins to the user group.

Comment: The url `https://index.docker.io/v1/` looks like the url for an image called "v1" whereas in your Dockerfile, it looks liek you are trying to pull and image called "myImage" with the tag "v1"

Answer (score 0):

Your docker file should have a full image reference. `<registry>/<repository>/<imagename>:<image_tag>` if not, the docker demon will always try to pull image from the default docker registry. Change the `FROM` part of your `DOCKERFILE` to contain the full image path. It will work